# Reflect up 5 levels for a Property?

Tags: reflection, enterprise-library, stack-frame

I have implemented a CustomTraceListener for use with Enterprise Library 5. From the TraceData method, I need to crawl the stack up 6 levels to my class that had the actual logging call, I need a property from there. I don't think I want a StackFrame climb because that only gets the class and not the object, right? What is the best way to get at the (string) property I need?

This is on Framework 4.0, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get (parameters) values from the .NET stack from the program itself, only methods, properties, classes, ie: anything that comes from .NET metadata.

If you want values, here are a some solutions:

- instrument your code before compilation, adding lines of code to capture parameters values
- instrument your code after compilation, with things like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) for example (disclaimer: I'm not affiliated in any way)
- write a .NET profiler, but this must be an external program. There a existing tools that do this already, like this one: [CLR profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569269). Version 4 of the CLR profiler (available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2011/02/01/clrprofiler-v4-released.aspx)) comes with the source.